# react not working with bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am checking the login via jquery using this methods:

```
module.exports = {
    login: function(username, pass, cb) {
        if (localStorage.token) {
            if (cb) cb(true)
            return
        }
        this.getToken(username, pass, (res) => {
            if (res.authenticated) {
                localStorage.token = res.token
                if (cb) cb(true)
            } else {
                if (cb) cb(false)
            }
        })
    },        

    logout: function() {
        delete localStorage.token
    },

    loggedIn: function() {
        return !!localStorage.token
    },

    getToken: function(username, pass, cb) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/obtain-auth-token/',
            data: {
                email_or_username: username,
                password: pass
            },
            success: function(res){
                cb({
                    authenticated: true,
                    token: res.token
                })
            }
        })
    }, 
}
```

My login validation is working correctly, if the user and password are correct it redirects to app page. But if is incorrect I receive this message at terminal:

POST http://url_base/obtain-auth-token/ 400 (Bad Request)

and this element:

```
<p>Bad login information</p>
```

Does not appears at my login page.

I think that the problem is this error from jQuery but I don't know how to solve this.

I am using this repository how reference: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/auth.js

Here is my LoginPage:

'use strict'

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import '../../../css/login.css'
import '../../../css/animation.css'
import Logo from '../icons/Logo'
import auth from './auth'

class LoginPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            error: false,
            loggedIn: auth.loggedIn()
        }

    }

    handleSubmit(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()

        var username = this.refs.username.value
        var pass = this.refs.pass.value

        auth.login(username, pass, (loggedIn) => {
            if (loggedIn) {
                const { location } = this.props
                if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
                  browserHistory.push(location.state.nextPathname)
                } else {
                  browserHistory.push('app')
                }
            }
            else{
                this.setState({error:true});
            }
        })
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <div id="login" className="login">
                <div className="login-content">
                    <div id="login-content-container" className="login-content-container">
                        <Logo svgClass="login-content-container-logo" width="270" height="35"/>
                        <form className="login-content-container-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                          <input className="login-content-container-form-input" type="text" ref="username" placeholder="username"/>
                          <input className="login-content-container-form-input" type="password" ref="pass" placeholder="password"/>
                          <button className="login-content-container-form-button">login</button>
                        </form>
                        {this.state.error && (
                            <p>Bad login information</p>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginPage
```

Comment: You might be having wrong parameters error. check your server side and see the error you are having and paste it here

Comment: That is the question, I receive this error when I type username and/or password wrong. This will happen

Comment: Do you have any server side log.. this seems to be like a your server is expecting a different parameter

Comment: Do you want this? responseText: "{"password":["This field may not be blank."],"email_or_username":["This field may not be blank."]}"

Comment: You did only provide `success` callback, but no `error` callback to the `$.ajax` method. Since it's `4xx` HTTP header it should be handled separately from success-handling method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply because you haven't handled the ajax error callback in getToken

```
getToken: function(username, pass, cb) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/obtain-auth-token/',
            data: {
                email_or_username: username,
                password: pass
            },
            success: function(res){
                cb({
                    authenticated: true,
                    token: res.token
                })
            },
            error: function () { cb({authenticated: false}); }
        })
    },
```

Comment: guess I was late .. Nice!